# jquery load() method is useful for what?

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I have been playing around with jquery and the ajax load() method, although I can get it to work and pull data off other web pages and place it on the one I am working on, I cannot really see a useful reason to ever do that.  Any insight / practical examples would be great in understanding it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I find particularly useful about the `.load()` method is the ability to load an HTML fragment.  Passing the `id` of some container element on the page you're loading from will return only that element's contents.

Note that `.load()` is still subject to [CORS restrictions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

More reading here:  http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

Comment: thanks, I know what it does, I was looking for practical applications.